# How `set!` works in Racket when working with continuations?

Tags: racket, continuations

I have this code working code based on an example from wikipedia

```
(define (foo5)
  (define (control-state return)
    (define-syntax-rule
      (yield x) 
      (set! return (call/cc
                    (lambda (resume-here)
                      (set! control-state resume-here)
                      (return x)))))
    (yield 'foo)
    (yield 'bar)
    (yield 'tar)
    (return 'end))
  (thunk (call/cc control-state)))
```

I would never achieve this code by my self because the use of `set!` goes against every intuition there exists inside me.

First, `control-state` is local to `foo5`, okay, then I do `(define g (foo5))` in the top level, at this point, in my head `g` points to the same reference that `control-state` points, a closure somewhere in the memory.

Then I call `g` as `(g)` it evaluates up to `(set! control-state resume-here)` at this point is where my intuition breaks. In my head this will set the internal `control-state` symbol to `resume-here`, BUT IT CHANGES THE OUTER `g` ALSO?. How this is even possible?

Comment: The big leap, I think, is that `g` is *not* `control-state`, it is a suspended continuation "inside" `foo5`.

Comment: I will try to wrap my head around that

Comment: I'm still trying to work out the details of this one. Essentially, I consider `g` as "what remains of `foo5`", and the "what remains" part is updated in `yield`, before returning the value. Continuations can seriously mess with your head, so I might be completely wrong on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simpler than it looks.

First of all let's rewrite it, giving it a more obvious name and replacing the local macro with a function, to remove any confusion that a macro might be needed:

```
(define (yielder)
  (define (control-state return)
    (define (yield x)
      (set! return (call/cc (λ (resume-here)
                              (set! control-state resume-here)
                              (return x)))))
    (yield 1)
    (yield 2)
    (yield 3)
    (return 'end))
  (thunk (call/cc control-state)))
```

OK, so first of all notice that the top-level thing is `(define (yielder) ...)`, and *not* `(define yielder ...)`, so `yielder` is a function which, when called will return `(thunk ...)`: a function of no arguments.  That means that this:

```
(define g (yielder)
```

causes `g` to be bound to that function of no arguments.  In particular `g` is not the same thing as `control-state`, and neither is it a suspended continuation.  Nothing has happened yet as the function has not yet been called.  Further `g` is never changed by any assignment: the `control-state` binding it closes over *is* mutated, but the binding of `g` itself is nt.

So, when `g` *is* called then it immediately calls the current value of `control-state` with the current continuation: a function which, when called, will immediately return from the `call/cc` and hence from `g`: that function is bound to `return` inside `control-state`.

`control-state` then calls `(yield 1)` which starts to evaluate

```
(set! return (call/cc (λ (resume-here)
                        (set! control-state resume-here)
                        (return x)))))
```

So this then involves calling

```
(λ (resume-here)
  (set! control-state resume-here)
  (return x))
```

With `resume-here` bound to a continuation which, if invoked, will cause the value it's invoked with to be assigned to `return`.  It stashes this continuation into `control-state`, and then invokes the current value of `return` with the value of `x` which is `1`.  `return` then returns from that value from `g`: the assignment is not (yet) completed.

The next time `g` is called it does the same thing, creating a new `return` continuation and calling the current value of `control-state` with it as argument.  But that value is now the continuation that was stashed there on the last call.  So this now returns from the `call/cc` that was suspended by the invokation of the old value of `return` and completes the assignment before carrying on ... to the next `yield` call which does the same dance again except this time returning `2` from `g`.  And so on.

Essentially the two continuations perform this little interleaved dance where you're for each call of `g` you're making a new continuation which says how to return from that call, and then invoking a continuation which restarts the body, stashing a new continuation for the next step before returning from `g`.

This is fiddly to understand but not impossible if you pore over it a bit.

Comment: So every time I do `(blabla (call/cc (lambda (k) ...)) foo`,  `k`  is the continuation of that `call/cc` if I dot not call it the expression is never continued, is this reasoning correct? `foo` for example will not be evaluated until I call `k` somewhere in the code?!

Comment: @geckos: if `blabla` is `begin` or something like it then yes.  If it's some function then it depends on the order in which arguments are evaluated which is undefined.

Comment: I didn't know that the order of evaluation of arguments were undefined in scheme, I always though that it was left to right, thanks!